# WebRequest response content

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I'm trying to find out response content of the given url using HttpWebRequest

```
var targetUri = new Uri("http://www.foo.com/Message/CheckMsg?msg=test");
  var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(targetUri);
  var webRequestResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
```

The above code always returns the home page (http://www.foo.com) content. I was expecting http://www.foo.com/Message page content. something wrong or am I missing something?

Comment: Does the site require authentication? You're likely getting the content of the page being redirected to.

Comment: No, it doesn't required authentication.@SimonWhitehead

Comment: Does it perhaps require a verb other than `GET`?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Is the CheckMsg is an html or php file? When I'm accessing websites using webrequest I always have to use the extension. Otherwise the website will think it's a folder. I would recommend trying to add that.
var targetUri = new Uri("http://www.foo.com/Message/CheckMsg.html?msg=test");

Comment: Its MVC controller action, the response will be displayed in cshtml page (ASP.NET MVC) @Daniel Kiss